# Object became a like a grid, how to turn it back solid?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, wireframe

I was creating an object and a rig when suddenly the object turned into a grid instead of showing off the default grey material.

*How it looks right now:*

[image: object wireframe]

How do I make it solid again?

Answer (score 1):

Key <kbd>Z</kbd>. This will toggle between *Wireframe* (what you are in) and *Solid* view.